# Print Hadamard matrix of order N

Tags: beginner, rust

Problem statement: The \$n\$-by-\$n\$ Hadamard matrix \$H(n)\$ is a boolean matrix with the remarkable property that any two rows differ in exactly \$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{2}}\$ bits. \$H(1)\$ is a \$1\$-by-\$1\$ matrix with the single entry true, and for \$n > 1\$, \$H(2n)\$ is obtained by aligning four copies of \$H(n)\$ in a large square, and then inverting all of the entries in the lower right n-by-n copy. Write a program that takes one command-line argument `n` and prints \$H(n)\$. Assume that `n` is a power of \$2\$.

This is one of my self-imposed challenges in Rust to become better at it. The problem was taken from [Sedgewick Exercise 1.4.29](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/).

Here is my code:

```
use clap::Parser;
use std::ops::RangeFrom;
use std::process::exit;

const VALID_ORDERS: RangeFrom<usize> = 1..;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Arguments {
    #[arg(index = 1)]
    order: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::parse();
    let order: usize = arguments.order;

    let hadamard_matrix = match create_hadamard_matrix(order) {
        Ok(hadamard_matrix) => hadamard_matrix,
        Err(error) => {
            eprintln!("{}", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    };

    for v in hadamard_matrix {
        for i in v {
            if i {
                print!("* ");
            } else {
                print!("  ");
            }
        }
        println!();
    }
}

fn create_hadamard_matrix(order: usize) -> Result<Vec<Vec<bool>>, String> {
    if !VALID_ORDERS.contains(&order) {
        return Err(format!("Order must be at least {}.", VALID_ORDERS.start));
    }

    if !is_power_of_two(order) {
        return Err("Order must be a power of 2.".to_string());
    }

    let mut hadamard_matrix = vec![vec![false; order]; order];
    hadamard_matrix[0][0] = true;

    let mut k: usize = 1;

    while k < order {
        for i in 0..k {
            for j in 0..k {
                hadamard_matrix[i + k][j] = hadamard_matrix[i][j];
                hadamard_matrix[i][j + k] = hadamard_matrix[i][j];
                hadamard_matrix[i + k][j + k] = !hadamard_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        k += k;
    }

    Ok(hadamard_matrix)
}

fn is_power_of_two(order: usize) -> bool {
    let mut k: usize = 1;

    while k <= order / 2 {
        k *= 2;
    }

    order - k == 0
}
```

Is there any way that I can improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> fn is_power_of_two(order: usize) -> bool {
>     let mut k: usize = 1;
>
>     while k <= order / 2 {
>         k *= 2;
>     }
>
>     order - k == 0
> }
> ```

That looks like a way to do it, I'm not 100% sure because it is a bit subtle, but in any case you don't need to write it: there is a built-in [`is_power_of_two`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.is_power_of_two) for `usize` (and other integer types) already.